# PHP array Conversion to C#

Tags: c#, php

I was wondering how I can convert this PHP code to C#:

```
array("id" => $intID, "clients" => array(), "max" => $max, "requests" => 0);
```

In C# I have this:

```
string[,] waddleObject = new string[,] 
    { 
        { "ID", ID.ToString() },
        { "clients", new string[] { } },
        { "max", max.ToString() },
        { "requests", "0" }
   };
```

That C# doesn't work, any ideas what I can do here?

Comment: You might consider using a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You have an int, a client array and two other ints. Are you sure you don't want to model these into class properties instead of sticking them in one container that disregards their types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Dictionary which is available in C# like this.

```
       Dictionary<string,List<string>> waddleObject  = new  Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
       var item = new List<string>.Add(Id.ToString();
       waddleObject.Add("Id",item);
```

The reason is that you can find the key in O(1). Like this

```
        List<string> val = waddleObject["Id"];
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` :

```
 Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    dictionary.Add(ID, new List<string> { max, request });
```

Comment: Ok it was just a quick answer and i edited it as fast as i could so plz remove your downvote